# HTMLUnite infinite loop stackoverflow

Tags: java, javascript, web, html-parsing, htmlunit

I'm trying to get this page with HTMLUnit but it seems that HTMLUnit goes on an infinite loop and crashs.

I've been tried to find the reason but I gived up.
I tried:

- Get the latest code from SVN HTMLUnit
- Use different Browsers
- Try to debug but I could not find the reason.

If I use 
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

I can get the site but important scripts are not executed. So, the problem is about JavaScript.

Here a example code that runs to loop:

```
String url = "http://www.tjpe.jus.br/processos/consulta1grau/oleConsultaProcesso.asp?
nume=00123335620128170990&modalidade=6";

    final List collectedAlerts = new ArrayList();
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setAlertHandler(new CollectingAlertHandler(collectedAlerts));
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
    try {
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient
        .getPage(url);

        page1.asXml();
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is the error:

```
Jan 4, 2013 11:39:05 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Jan 4, 2013 11:39:05 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Jan 4, 2013 11:39:43 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine     
handleJavaScriptException
INFO: Caught script exception
======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[java.lang.RuntimeException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking go
at   
 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run
(JavaScriptEngine.java:665)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:587)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call
(ContextFactory.java:534)

...

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.reflect.Method.copy(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.copyMethod(Unknown Source)

....

    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:432)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

The URL that I'm using is public so, be free to access it.

Please, I appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the URL you are trying to acces is having some Java script errors. Try

```
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks for your help, but I think you did not saw that I'm still using your suggestion with no effect.